# undefined method `referrals' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am implementing a referral system rails 5.1. I want to referrals up to 8th generation. 
I have an affiliation class as below:

```
class Affiliation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :affiliate, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "affiliate_id"
  belongs_to :referred, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "referred_id"
     validates_presence_of :affiliate, :referred
     validates_uniqueness_of :referred_id
       private
        def validate
          errors.add_to_base("Affiliate and Referrer can't be the same 
        user.") if affiliate and (affiliate == referred)
        end
       end
```

my User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :affiliations, :foreign_key => "affiliate_id", :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :referrals, :through => :affiliations, :source => :referred
  # map.affiliate_referral 'a/:referrer_code', :controller => 
 'referrals', :action => 'new'
  def affiliate_link
    "https://localhost:3000/members/new/?referrer_code=#
    {self.affiliate_code}"
 end
```

Now the referral system is working I can create members to their referrer

the challenge is how to view 1st generation down to 8th generation.
Im getting this error:

```
undefined method `referrals' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f48e4c2d2e0>
```

I am able to referrals for first generation but from 2nd upward its not working .

Any help please...???
Here is my dashboard controller

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
         def dashboard
                 # storage for referrals and affilations through eight 
         generations

           #generate first generation referrals
             def flatten_scopes(scopes)
            scopes.inject([]) { |a,r| r.is_a?(Array) ? a += flatten_scopes(r) : a.push(r) }
   end

       @firstgeners = referral_gen(current_user)
       @secondgeners ||= []
       @thirdgeners ||= []
       @fourthgeners ||= []
      @fifthgeners ||= []
      @sixthgeners ||= []
     @seventhgeners ||= []
     @eightgeners ||= []
            #loop first generation referrals to get the affiliates to 
         form our second 
        generation affiliations 
        #@firstgeners = @firstgeners1.flatten

        #@secondgeners1 = []
               @firstgeners = flatten_scopes(@firstgeners)
             if  @firstgeners.any?
            @firstgeners.each do |u| 
        if u.referrals.any?

           @secondgeners << u.referrals
           end
       end
        end

      #@secondgeners = @secondgeners1.flatten
      #from second generation referrals generate the affiliations 
      # @thirdgeners1 = []
      @secondgeners = flatten_scopes(@secondgeners)
      if @secondgeners.any?
      @secondgeners.each do |u| 
      if u.referrals.any?
     @thirdgeners << u.referrals
       end
     end
    end
    #@thirdgeners = @thirdgeners1.flatten

     @thirdgeners = flatten_scopes(@thirdgeners)
     #from third generation referrals generate the affiliations
    if @thirdgeners.any?
      @thirdgeners.each do |u| 
     if u.referrals.any?
      @fourthgeners << u.referrals
    end
    end
    end 
    #@fourthgeners = @fourthgeners1.flatten



      #from third generation referrals generate the affiliations
        @fourthgeners = flatten_scopes(@fourthgeners)
        if @fourthgeners.any?
       @fourthgeners.each do |u| 
       if u.referrals.any?
       @fifthgeners << u.referrals
       end
       end
       end 
    # @fifthgeners = @fifthgeners1.flatten

     @fifthgeners = flatten_scopes(@fifthgeners)
     if @fifthgeners.any?
        @fifthgeners.each do |u| 
         if u.referrals.any?
           @sixthgeners << u.referrals
          end
          end
          end

       #  @sixthgeners = @sixthgeners1.flatten 
        @sixthgeners = flatten_scopes(@sixthgeners)
         if @sixthgeners.any?
          @sixthgeners.each do |u| 
          if u.referrals.any?
          @seventhgeners << u.referrals
          end
         end
         end
         #@seventhgeners = @seventhgeners.flatten

        @secondgeners = flatten_scopes(@seventhgeners)
         if @seventhgeners.any?
           @seventhgeners.each do |u| 
           if u.referrals.any?
            @eightgeners << u.referrals
           end
          end
           end 

         #@eightgeners = @eightgeners1.flatten
         end

         #generate all affiliations  of current_user

               def referral_gen(user)
                 referrals = user.referrals
                 return referrals
               end
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], with emphasis on the word **minimal**? Where exactly does that error originate from? (Which line?) Can you cut down that code sample to some **minimal** reproduction steps? About 90-95% of the code in your question can be deleted.

Comment: What line is the error referencing? The error is telling you that you're calling `referrals` on an array of records - not 1 specific record.

Comment: i just added the line below in answer section please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now i get it to work.
full user object is only available at the first call of the collection `@user.referrals` after this level previous calls couldnot get uniq associations for   the group of users referred by this user. so I did something like this: I used the referral code from the database to search and return the right referrals. it works upwards till 8th generation even if it is slow on performance.

```
if @firstgeners.any?
  @firstgeners.each do |u|
  @users.each do |e|
    if e.referrer_code == u.affiliate_code
      @secondgeners.push(e)
    end
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is from the Dashboard Controller this line

```
                  if u.referrals.any?
                  @thirdgeners << u.referrals
```

This line is inside  the block below..  once my 1st generation referrals have referred other people. The error occurs. If they haven't it works well. just calling my referrals it works well since I have the active record association as that. But I tot current_user.referrals would give me arrays of users. And I can loop through them and get their referrals as well like user.referrals and repeat until 8 times. But not working like that.

```
 @secondgeners = flatten_scopes(@secondgeners)
       if @secondgeners.any?
           @secondgeners.each do |u| 
           if u.referrals.any?
              @thirdgeners << u.referrals
         end
         end
        end
```